# Jail user in production

Tags: user-management

I have an offline Ubuntu 22 machine used in production
I want to jail the user from accessing files in the OS, what’s the best approach to this task?
I’ve been looking on chroot and jailkit

Comment: By Ubuntu 22 do you mean Ubuntu Core 22; as the *year* products (22) are different to the far more widely used *year.month* (22.04) systems, ie. 22 != 22.04 though of course they are similar.  Applications run *contained* by default on 22 unlike 22.04 so security is higher by default.

Comment: The historic method still works very well for most use cases: Give users "user" accounts that lack admin permission, so they can only mess up their own /home directory and nothing else. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1418630/edit) to clearly explain why this classic, time-tested method won't work for you. The better you explain the problem, the better solutions and advice we can provide.